# Create a date range dropdown with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I'm using Ransack for some simple searching of one of my models.

I would like to add a dropdown to the search with entries like 'Today', 'Yesterday', 'Current week', etc which would operate on the `created_at` field. Also it would be nice to have an entry in this dropdown to reveal 2 date boxes to pick a custom date range. How do I go about this?

One way that I can think of doing this is for the dropdown to populate the two (hidden) date boxes via JavaScript, I just don't know how I could easily reselect the proper entry in the dropdown when reloading the page.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
distance_of_time_in_words(obj.created_at,Time.now)+" ago"
```

This will return result like this:

> about 2 hours ago

Comment: This is not what I asked.